# Noisy stereo when engine running

Tags: audio, gm, barina

I have a 2009 Holden Barina. I turned the car on to "Accessories" and the radio was working fine.  I turned the car on, and now there is a noise coming from the speakers and no music.  The same thing happens with the CD player.  What happened and how can I fix this?

Comment: I have edited your question to give it a more descriptive title ("repair question" applies to pretty much everything on this site), and to improve the grammar/punctuation to make it easier to read.  Please check that it looks okay, and perhaps when asking future questions you could take another minute or two to proofread.

Comment: Sounds like you have engine noise possibly coming through your wiring? Do you have an aftermarket audio system..?

Comment: Start by checking the battery voltage when the car is running, if the alternator is bad it can either produce a bad voltage (too high?) which will make the radio (and possibly other electronics) behave strangely. If everything's good, I suggest you disconnect the alternator temporarily, start the car and see if the radio is still working; the alternator may be damaged and spit out poorly-rectified AC which will obviously wreak havoc and possibly damage electronics.

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it this should not happen. As have you white noise coming from your speakers it would seem that your radio/CD set has broken down internally. A check over from a competent auto electrician will determine if the fault is internal or down to any items such as mega-bass units external to the set, or even the aerial lead coming unplugged. A damaged external aerial could also cause this as far as the radio reception goes, but would not account for the CD not playing. Have you a set you could substitute with as a test.

Answer (score 0):

Noise - means radio mode is working. Try to insert other CD, as your current CD might be damaged

Comment: Both the CD and radio is said to be working fine on the accessories key position, so it can't be that.

Answer (score 0):

If your car has points ignition, It may be a failed condenser. The sparking at the points creates interference, and your speaker wires could be inducting and amplifying the signals.